# Есть ли разница между этими конструкторами производного класса?

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, конструктор

Есть базовый класс с конструктором и производный класс использующий конструктор базового:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    int v;
    Base(int v_) {
        v = v_;
    }
    Base() {

    }
};

class NewClass:public Base {
    int u;
public:
    NewClass(int v_, int u_) :Base(v_) {
        u = u_;
    }
    NewClass(int v_, int u_,int) {
        this->Base::Base(v_);
        u = u_;
    }
    void foo(int v_, int u_) {
        this->NewClass::NewClass(v_, u_);
    }
};
```

Есть ли разница между первым и вторым конструкторами и безопасно ли использовать функцию `foo`

Answer (score 4):

> Есть ли разница

Разница в том, что `this->Base::Base(v_);` вообще не должно компилироваться. GCC и Clang [отказываются](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5MmaDBAah5NBmBRwDsfAAwBBAA4iARgzzIQHPQusK8LAgoBuHAMw7dNpSswQ7DxwD6AJTqWpYenjaO6i4AIk4Bru6emrHhnsqqECGa7uk2qeGFbkV6siqKAHKYAO4AwnKCIIYmZl6qock2fgoiSeEtpub51tX1jb72CaS2UyLBCiCZPoE5YVaR1iIx8fP9G9aFBwpjDRWT/gEzPfPk9mtdmwQIeIIAtK7YyyBL3hCr%2Bwim22rl2iRKxyOQKcqDw6AUADNUKgLtNZg55g8RpFnq8Pi5sKdGj8iedAjNMYCUho0npijwpEFGNIAKxSUgsaTadmoaR1fj8BTCMQSdRcFy0dkELmMpkAaxAXAAHAA6bTaAAsGq4tCVGqVGi4%2BpZADZmVINezOVJuaReVJ2U1tKRpTbGaQ4LAYIgUKgALb6PAMTBkCgQNABoMhkDAACc9ARQYIIaaECMMtIRjsTGIAE9pJLSBG/Zh7AB5FgMfNu0hYP2sYDBjP4YiYZAEPCOTBNGuYAAebZEyYL7L8mAYGdMRmIOdzdQwkikhYIxDwfpHTOYbBQAt4jDwRiakCZqH0HdQLB7b0EBHQoM4vH4tA0CjeAHUmAwGK%2B3/2V0xX30TB0FYDtkDeENiBIQRHVEcRJFoTdWStDN7T7JUTTeE0NQUYBkGQBRYxVWgFAgXBCBIMUJRmedI2DYgqMQhR%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%2Br6qapWQwV5rTMcZB9H0AJHFoWMAnEgI%2B2wvqkxTSgRttMaJr2qa/RmggKyrZtMHrNhloWvBW3bTtuwzbbkCHRdCzHMrbSnE65wXC7V3XPbNwbHdWPug9HpPM88AvHsAHob3QRfKZ4ZhkxvKH4LoWH4cSoucL9QR06cXOVXEnG1cogmaKT/HxRccm7utz26b20ZoqX2/tA5cGDqHcOZUnZCwSqLN2KUNLugakgOWQ4U6fxAC4VWlkNZMDsnPBylVdZSFci4Q2zxvJ%2BVvvfHORFxL/1CoAhmjs4pwKjtVd2yDQre1ARqAOQdtAh21NA6QkcEbRySjw2GXASGuyYUyLsQ0N6cg1EAA) собирать этот код.

Конструкторы нельзя вызывать таким способом.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 компилирует

Comment: видимо у `microsoft` свои взгляды на этот счет

Comment: @kust Это уже причуды студии.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Наверно.

Answer (score 1):

При создании обьекта, если вы не пишете конструктор по умолчанию, компилятором  генерируется  конструктор по умолчанию, который конструирует члены значениями по умолчанию. Для класса `Base`, написав `Base() = default;` вы явно требуете сделать это, облегчив работу компилятора и пользователя(сразу понятны ваши намерения). Но, когда вы пишете `Base() { }` то это явное требование того, что конструктор по умолчанию ничего не должен делать, что означает оставить  член в неопределенном состоянии, а значит нарушать инвариант создаваемого обьекта(свойство обьекта сохранять определенное состояние). Не думаю, что какой то компилятор пропустит это без сообщения об ошибке, тем более что  во втором конструкторе производного класса вы пытаетесь создать обьект на основе такого, не имеющее определенного состояния, обьекта. Другое дело, если вы напишете:

```
class Base {
public:
    int v;
    Base(int v_) {
        v = v_;
    }
    Base() = default;
};

class NewClass :public Base {

public:
    int u;
    NewClass(int v_, int u_) :Base(v_) {
        u = u_;
    }
    NewClass(int v_, int u_, int) {
        v = v_;
        u = u_;
    }   
};
```

Но лучше, если вы не станете инициализировать члены значением по умолчанию, а потом выполнять присвоение, а сразу создавать их с такими значениями:

```
class Base {
public:
    int v;
    Base(int v_) : v(v_) {}
    Base() = default;
};

class NewClass :public Base {   
public:
    int u;
    NewClass(int v_, int u_) :Base(v_), u(u_) { }
    NewClass(int v_, int u_, int) : NewClass(v_, u_) {} 
};
```

p.s. плюс замечание в  ответе от  HolyBlackCat

Comment: virtual ~Base() = default;

Comment: @StrangeOwl, верно, но, во первых необьязательно, во вторых  демонстрация только для данных конструкторов.  Я же не класс написал, а ответил на вопрос. Вы лучше оформляйте вопрос: "все ли абстрактные классы должны иметь виртуальный деструктор? ".